# Can a Wordpress fixed footer be changed to a responsive one?

Tags: css, wordpress

We are a small art gallery building a wordpress website - you can see the work in progress here:http://kiraaskaroff.com/BB_Test2/

The footer looks great on a computer but with its fixed layout it looks rubbish on a mobile device (part disappears etc)

```
* footer */

#footer-content { margin-top: 60px; max-width:978px; min-width:320px;  height:230px;     overflow:hidden; padding-top:0px;  padding-left:200px; font-family:Georgia; color:#3F3F3F;  font-size:12px; text-align:left; }

#footer-left { float:left; width:199px;  height:182px; overflow:hidden;  }
#footer-mid1 { float:left; width:230px; height:182px; overflow:hidden; }
#footer-mid2 { float:left; width:138px;  height:182px; overflow:hidden; }
#footer-right { float:left; width:180px;  height:182px; overflow:hidden; }

.footer-header { font-family:Georgia, font-size:14px ; font-weight: bold; display:block;     color:#3F3F3F; padding-bottom:16px;text-align:left; }

.footer-social-a { display:inline; padding-right:5px; padding-top:18px;text-align:left; }

.styles #page .site-info a {
font-size: 12px;}
```

Any help making it look better on a mobile would be amazing!

Comment: Hiya, StackOverflow is more about finding resolutions to specific programming problems, eg "why is this code not working?" — this is likely to get closed because how to achieve what you're after is a complex design question involving lots of variables with all sorts of potential solutions. Googling for tutorials on responsive design or asking for help on a web design forum will yield better results.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some research into media queries, which will allow you to apply different CSS at different screen sizes.  Because even if you get it looking correct on mobile-sized screens, it'll still look broken on sizes between mobile and desktop (try resizing your browser on desktop to see what I mean).

For example, your desktop footer has for columns - there might be some screen sizes where you want two rows of two columns, while on mobile you probably want one column with four rows.

To get you started, adding this at the bottom of your stylesheet should help with your specific question (one column with four rows):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
    #footer-content {
        height: auto; /* Remove the fixed height - that's the reason not all the footer is visible */
        padding-left: 2%; /* On desktop you have a lot of space on the left - it's not needed on mobile */
    }

    #footer-left,
    #footer-mid1,
    #footer-mid2,
    #footer-right {
        width: 100%; /* Make each column takes the full width available */
        height: auto; /* If you leave the fixed heights from the desktop version you'll have strange gaps */
        padding-bottom: 10px; /* Make sure you have a minimum gap between the rows */
    }
}
```

I haven't fully tested, but it should do as a starting point.

Comment: Hi Hobo - thats amazing - thank you so much for taking the time - your answer is extremely enlightening! thank you!